# using FileStream to save image but image is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, base64, filestream

I'm getting an image from a base64 string, stored in a datatable. This string pulls successfully and is a valid base64 string, as I have tested it on free image decode websites and it decodes it back to the image I originally uploaded.

Now, I am trying to write the image to a file and no matter what I try, it fails to create the image file properly. **The image only shows if I return it to a View as `File(imageBytes, "image/jpeg")`**

Here is my code:

```
            string imagepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), client.ClientId + "_task" + task.TaskId + "_TaskReport.jpg");

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(myDataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString()); // this works elsewhere, but for some reason only when returning the image to the view as a FileResult


            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length); // this line creates the bad image!
                imageFile.Flush();
            }
```

What is wrong with my code? Why does it work with the mvc FileResult and not when converting to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to write file

```
byte[] b= //Your Image File in bytes;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\data.jpg", b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {                            
                        System.IO.MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                        file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                        byte[] data = target.ToArray();                        
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return View("Index",model);
            }
            return View();
        }
```